# Use RowSplitter with UniformGrid or something to obtain desired result

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am fairly new to wpf so bear with me.

My problem is, I have 4 graph controls placed one above the other that show in a popup window. All 4 are shown originally by default, but after the windows is displayed the user has a choice to un check a checkbox in the ribbon control to turn off one or more of the graphs. I use a UniformGrid because the remaining graphs will auto size to take up the remaining space.

I now need to add a RowSplitter so the user can control the the height of each visible graph. The top of the top graph should be anchored to the top of the window, and the bottom of the bottom graph should be anchored to the bottom of the window. When a user slides the RowSplitter between 2 graphs it should effect the height of both of them.

I have made a simple test project to try and work through.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Background="LightGray"  Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Content="Graph 1" Name="Graph1Vis" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Graph 2" Name="Graph2Vis" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Graph 3" Name="Graph3Vis" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Graph 4" Name="Graph4Vis" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto"  Columns="1">
            <Label Content="Graph 1" Background="Azure" Grid.Row="0" 
                   Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph1Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" Height="8" Background="DarkSlateBlue"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Label Content="Graph 2" Background="Lavender" Grid.Row="2" 
               Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph2Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="3" Width="Auto" Height="8" Background="DarkSlateBlue"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Graph 3" Background="Moccasin" Grid.Row="4"
               Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph3Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="5" Width="Auto" Height="8" Background="DarkSlateBlue"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Graph 4" Background="Beige" Grid.Row="6"
               Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph4Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would it be easier to let the user resize the popup window (and thus resizes the uniform grid and graphs within)?

Comment: There are 4 graphs one on top of the other. Users at times want graph 1 to take up 50% of the available screen and graph 2, 3 and 4 to take up the remaining, or many other combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea would be to actually add/remove the rows from your grid. This takes a bit of adjustment for the other elements, but makes using grid/gridsplitter possible in the way you're aiming for I think. The solution can be kept quite generic. A bonus is that the row height is remembered, so if you reveal a graph again it is shown in its previous height. Also, the other graphs will proportionally take up freed space when a row is removed, which seems the right behavior.

I'm not using a row per gridsplitter, I'm just putting one at the bottom of each row (except the last). The xaml part:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="panelVisibilities" Background="LightGray"  Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Content="Graph 1" x:Name="Graph1Vis" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="GraphVis_Click"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Graph 2" x:Name="Graph2Vis" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="GraphVis_Click"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Graph 3" x:Name="Graph3Vis" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="GraphVis_Click"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Graph 4" x:Name="Graph4Vis" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="GraphVis_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="graphGrid" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Graph 1" Background="Azure"  Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph1Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="2" Background="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph1Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Graph 2" Background="Lavender"  Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph2Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="2" Background="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph2Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="Graph 3" Background="Moccasin" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph3Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="2" ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="2" Background="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph3Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Content="Graph 4" Background="Beige" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph4Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private List<RowDefinition> _rows; // rows in graphGrid
    private List<CheckBox> _visibilityCheckboxes; // checkboxes that determine graph visibilities
    private Dictionary<int, List<UIElement>> _elementsByRow = new Dictionary<int, List<UIElement>>(); // map of elements per row


    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _visibilityCheckboxes = this.panelVisibilities.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().ToList();
        _rows = this.graphGrid.RowDefinitions.ToList();

        // create map of elements per row
        var elements = this.graphGrid.Children.Cast<UIElement>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _rows.Count; i++)
        {
            _elementsByRow.Add(i, elements.Where(e => Grid.GetRow(e) == i).ToList());
        }

        // check counts (optional)
        if (_rows.Count != _visibilityCheckboxes.Count)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Graph count does not match checkbox count.");


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the visibility checkboxes click.
    /// Adds/removes rows from the graphGrid, and adjusts the other elements accordingly.
    /// </summary>
    private void GraphVis_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chbx = sender as CheckBox;

        if (chbx != null && _visibilityCheckboxes.Contains(chbx))
        {
            int actualIndex = GetActualIndex(chbx); // row index at which the change occurs
            int originalIndex = _visibilityCheckboxes.IndexOf(chbx); // original index of the inserted row
            bool isChecked = (bool)chbx.IsChecked;

            RepositionControls(actualIndex, isChecked); 

            if (isChecked)
            {
                this.graphGrid.RowDefinitions.Insert(actualIndex, _rows[originalIndex]); // add row
                foreach (var element in _elementsByRow[originalIndex])
                    Grid.SetRow(element, actualIndex); // set element's grid.row to inserted row number
            }
            else
                this.graphGrid.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(actualIndex); // remove row
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines at which row number the change needs to occur.
    /// E.g. when checking chbx3, but only chbx1 is already checked (chbx2 is not), 
    /// the index of change (zero based) is 1 and not 2.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="chbx">Checkbox that was just changed</param>
    private int GetActualIndex(CheckBox chbx)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var c in _visibilityCheckboxes)
        {
            if (c == chbx) break;
            if ((bool)c.IsChecked) i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves elements to the appropriate grid row
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startIndex">Row number, at which the change occurs</param>
    /// <param name="isChecked">True if adding row, false when removing row</param>
    private void RepositionControls(int startIndex, bool isChecked)
    {
        if (!isChecked) startIndex++; // e.g. remove at row1 --> elements in row2, row3.. need to be adjusted

        // get all elements that need row adjustment (IsMeasureValid is false for non-displayed elements - is there a better property to use?)
        var elementsToMove = this.graphGrid.Children.Cast<UIElement>().Where(e => Grid.GetRow(e) >= startIndex && e.IsMeasureValid);

        foreach (var element in elementsToMove)
        {
            // increase or decrease grid.row property
            Grid.SetRow(element, Grid.GetRow(element) + (isChecked ? 1 : -1)); 
        }
    }
}
```

A possible improvement would be to always remove the gridsplitter from the bottom most graph, that would not be too hard to figure out I guess.

Comment: I have been trying to make a custom grid that would do this but I could never get it working. I like this solution because To add another graph and make it 5 there is no alterations to the code behind. Just add the check box, splitter, and graph to the xaml. Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: Thanks for the code effort. It is something that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the idea:
Build a Grid with 4 rows, each have 1 graph.
add 3 rectangles as the splitter buttons to the grid with their Grid.RowSpan set to 4.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="testwpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        MouseMove="Window_MouseMove_1" MouseUp="Window_MouseUp_1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Name="row1" Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Name="row2" Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Name="row3" Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Green"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Blue"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="Red"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Fill="Yellow"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#5000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10" Name="splitter1" MouseDown="splitter_MouseDown_1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0,40,0,0"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#5000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10" Name="splitter2" MouseDown="splitter_MouseDown_1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0,80,0,0"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#5000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10" Name="splitter3" MouseDown="splitter_MouseDown_1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0,120,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    FrameworkElement dragginSplitter = null;
    private void splitter_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        dragginSplitter = sender as FrameworkElement;
    }
    private void Window_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dragginSplitter != null)
            dragginSplitter.Margin = new Thickness(0, e.GetPosition(this).Y, 0, 0);
        if (splitter2.Margin.Top < splitter1.Margin.Top + 10) splitter2.Margin = new Thickness(0, splitter1.Margin.Top + 10, 0, 0);
        if (splitter3.Margin.Top < splitter2.Margin.Top + 10) splitter3.Margin = new Thickness(0, splitter2.Margin.Top + 10, 0, 0);
        row1.Height = new GridLength(splitter1.Margin.Top);
        row2.Height = new GridLength(splitter2.Margin.Top - splitter1.Margin.Top);
        row3.Height = new GridLength(splitter3.Margin.Top - splitter2.Margin.Top);
    }
    private void Window_MouseUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        dragginSplitter = null;
    }
```

important notes for Window_MouseMove_1:

1. top margin of draggingSplitter is equal to the Y position of mouse, whenever a splitter is dragged.
2. splitters should not pass each other so we check their top margins whenever a splitter is dragged.
3. height of the rows of the grid (Not the contents of the grid) is calculated according to the top margins of the splitters, whenever a splitter is dragged.

---

### EDIT:

---

I modified the code and added various conditions to satisfy the hide/show need.

```
<Window x:Class="testwpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        MouseMove="Window_MouseMove_1" MouseUp="Window_MouseUp_1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Name="row1" Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Name="row2" Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Name="row3" Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Name="row4" Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Green"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Blue"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="Red"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Fill="Yellow"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#5000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10" Name="splitter1" MouseDown="splitter_MouseDown_1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0,40,0,0"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#5000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10" Name="splitter2" MouseDown="splitter_MouseDown_1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0,80,0,0"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#5000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10" Name="splitter3" MouseDown="splitter_MouseDown_1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0,120,0,0"/>
        <WrapPanel Grid.RowSpan="4">
            <CheckBox Name="check1" Content="graph1" IsChecked="True" Checked="CheckBox_Checked_1" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked_1"/>
            <CheckBox Name="check2" Content="graph2" IsChecked="True" Checked="CheckBox_Checked_1" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked_1"/>
            <CheckBox Name="check3" Content="graph3" IsChecked="True" Checked="CheckBox_Checked_1" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked_1"/>
            <CheckBox Name="check4" Content="graph4" IsChecked="True" Checked="CheckBox_Checked_1" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked_1"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

xaml changes:
4 checkboxes are added and the 4th row is named.

```
FrameworkElement dragginSplitter = null;
private void splitter_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    dragginSplitter = sender as FrameworkElement;
}

private void Window_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dragginSplitter != null)
    {
        dragginSplitter.Margin = new Thickness(0, e.GetPosition(this).Y, 0, 0);
        updateSplitters();
    }
}

private void updateSplitters()
{
    if (splitter2.Margin.Top < splitter1.Margin.Top + 10) splitter2.Margin = new Thickness(0, splitter1.Margin.Top + 10, 0, 0);
    if (splitter3.Margin.Top < splitter2.Margin.Top + 10) splitter3.Margin = new Thickness(0, splitter2.Margin.Top + 10, 0, 0);

    if (check1.IsChecked.Value)
    {
        if (!check2.IsChecked.Value && !check3.IsChecked.Value && !check4.IsChecked.Value)
            row1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        else 
            row1.Height = new GridLength(splitter1.Margin.Top);
    }
    else
        row1.Height = new GridLength(0);

    if (check2.IsChecked.Value)
    {
        if (!check3.IsChecked.Value && !check4.IsChecked.Value)
            row2.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        else if(check1.IsChecked.Value)
            row2.Height = new GridLength(splitter2.Margin.Top - splitter1.Margin.Top);
        else
            row2.Height = new GridLength(splitter2.Margin.Top);
    }
    else
        row2.Height = new GridLength(0);

    if (check3.IsChecked.Value)
    {
        if (!check4.IsChecked.Value)
            row3.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        else if (check2.IsChecked.Value)
            row3.Height = new GridLength(splitter3.Margin.Top - splitter2.Margin.Top);
        else if (check1.IsChecked.Value)
            row3.Height = new GridLength(splitter3.Margin.Top - splitter1.Margin.Top);
        else
            row3.Height = new GridLength(splitter3.Margin.Top);
    }
    else
        row3.Height = new GridLength(0);

    row4.Height = check4.IsChecked.Value ? new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) : new GridLength(0);
}


private void Window_MouseUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    dragginSplitter = null;
}

private void CheckBox_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (check4 == null) return;//for when not yet completely loaded

    if (!check1.IsChecked.Value)
        splitter1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    if (!check2.IsChecked.Value)
        splitter2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    if (!check3.IsChecked.Value)
        splitter3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    if (!check4.IsChecked.Value)
    {
        splitter3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        if (!check3.IsChecked.Value)
            splitter2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        if (!check2.IsChecked.Value)
            splitter1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    if (check1.IsChecked.Value && (check2.IsChecked.Value || check3.IsChecked.Value || check4.IsChecked.Value))
        splitter1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    if (check2.IsChecked.Value && (check3.IsChecked.Value || check4.IsChecked.Value))
        splitter2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    if (check3.IsChecked.Value && check4.IsChecked.Value)
        splitter3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

    updateSplitters();
}
```

Changes in cs:

1. updateSplitters function is replaced with the previous logic for
   updating the splitters' margins.
2. when any checkbox is checked or unchecked, visibility of splitters change and updateSplitters is called.
3. updateSplitters does all the rest. not much to say except that the last visible row always has the GridUnitType of Star to fill the remaining space of the grid.

The only problem I found is that the lower contents of the Grid may fall out of the screen when window is resizing or one of the upper rows are being resized to a large Height value.

Comment: Interesting direction... I don't think it will support toggling the visibility on/off of one or multiple sections and have the rest fill the remaining space since it is declaring 4 RowDefinitions there will always be 4 spaces regardless if something is there to fill it.. Or am I wrong?

Comment: you can set the visibility of splitters to Collapsed, and set the Height of the desired rows to 0.

Comment: you're right, it takes a little more effort. however you can add a few lines of code forcing the splitter to stick to its adjacent splitter.

Comment: I have been playing around with this today, just some things I noticed. If we are not using a uniform grid anymore then why not use the <GridSplitter/> control? It would automatically re-size its neighbors. I have the demo working great with a GridSplitter control, until I try to hide one of the rows. It is possible to get the size of the control that was hidden and calculate how much to increase each of the remaining controls heights, but I have not been able to get that part working. Also when using the uniform grid when the user re-sizes the window the visible controls resize automaticaly.

Comment: There are many options in wpf when it comes to choosing between panels, each has its own weakness and strength. MSDN provides a good overview for panels: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx I also Suggest considering DockPanel as the container panel. (it always fills the window with its children when LastChildFill=True)

Comment: I haven't tried GridSplitter, but from what you said about it I'm sure this solution will work: set the Height of the hidden graph to zero but don't change its visibility, and instead only hide its corresponding GridSplitter (if necessary).

Comment: I just seem to keep going around in circles with this section, and am getting dizzy. :) I am able to get the grid splitters to work correctly, but as soon as I try to hide one or more of the sections it all goes down hill. I tried to set the row height to 0 but then when trying to resize it the remaining splitter picks it up as still there and resizes the row that was set to 0.

Comment: This solution worked for me, and I learned a little trying to implement it. I did however go with another solution but this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes I made...

***MainWindow.xaml:***

In this section, make sure to add the following:

[image]

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Background="LightGray" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Content="Graph 1" x:Name="Graph1Vis" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Graph 2" x:Name="Graph2Vis" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Graph 3" x:Name="Graph3Vis" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Graph 4" x:Name="Graph4Vis" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
            
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsChecked, ElementName=Graph1Vis, Converter={local:CheckedToLengthConverter}}"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsChecked, ElementName=Graph2Vis, Converter={local:CheckedToLengthConverter}}"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsChecked, ElementName=Graph3Vis, Converter={local:CheckedToLengthConverter}}"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsChecked, ElementName=Graph4Vis, Converter={local:CheckedToLengthConverter}}"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                
            <Label Content="Graph 1" Background="Azure" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph1Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" Height="8" Background="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph1Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <Label Content="Graph 2" Background="Lavender" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph2Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="3" Height="8" Background="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph2Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <Label Content="Graph 3" Background="Moccasin" Grid.Row="4" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph3Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="5" Width="Auto" Height="8" Background="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph4Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <Label Content="Graph 4" Background="Beige" Grid.Row="6" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Graph4Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

***MainWindow.xaml.cs***

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    {
public class CheckedToLengthConverter : System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return System.Convert.ToBoolean(value) ? new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) : new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Pixel);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
//etc...
```

I hope this is what you are looking for and let me know if you have any questions/concerns!

Also since you are just starting out, I will provide you with some helpful recommendations.

### Name

When using WPF, some elements do not have the property `Name`, which is why I recommend using `x:Name` whenever naming an element.

---

### GridSplitter

Whenever using `GridSplitter`, make sure to provide the following:

- VerticalAlignment
- HorizontalAlignment
- Width and/or Height

This will ensure that the `GridSplitter` will work.

In your example, each `GridSplitter` has a different `VerticalAlignment` value, which will case inconsistent results.  I recommend using `VerticalAlignment="Center"`.

---

### Grid/UniformGrid

I recommend using `Grid` over `UniformGrid`. `Grid` is arguably the most powerful layout container and gives much more freedom than that of `UniformGrid` (which is rarely used).

Comment: Thank you for your feed back and pointers, this is a lot cleaner then the solution I have been trying to make work. Unfortunately it has the same problem as mine does. This is the problem i am stuck on: If you un-check only graph 2 and leave graph 1, 3, and 4 visible and try to use the splitter between graph 1 and graph 3 it will not work as expected. You only end up effecting graph 2 which is supposed to be hidden. Ideally With only the 3 visible the splitters should control their immediately visible neighbor. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I was thinking of overriding the UniformGrid and allowing to control the height of individual items because the uniform grid you don't need to set a predetermined number of rows. Every attempt I have had using the grid I have run into issues with having to set the number of rows initially and tell those UI elements what row they belong in. Although every attempt to extend UniformGrid have failed mostly because Im not really sure what I am doing.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, however, I do not think `UniformGrid` works with `GridSplitter`. If you are fine with a not too pretty programmatic solution, I will work on one.

Comment: No GridSplitter does not work with UniformGrid, but I cannot think of a way to make it work with the Grid control. I think my only possibility is a programmatic solution at this point.